# Prove easy example of $p$-adic Liouville number: $\sum_{i\geq0}p^{i!}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$I want to prove that $\alpha := \sum_{i\geq0}p^{i!} \in \Z_p$ is a $p$-adic Liouville number.
$p$-adic Liouville number is defined as follows.

> $\alpha \in \Z_p$ is called a $p$-adic Liouvile number if
>   $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|n-\alpha|_p} = 0.$$

The following is what I tried. If I put $n = \sum_{i=0}^k p^{i!}$, then
$$\sqrt[n]{|n-\alpha|_p} = p^{-(k+1)!/n} = p^{-(k+1)!/\sum_{i=0}^k p^{i!}}.$$
I want $\text{power index} \to -\infty$, but I can't prove.

I read [this](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/cjm/2014/813924.pdf) and its references as I can, but I can't find the proof.
Although this article says the proof is easy, it seems rather difficult for me.

Comment: This is obviously not true. After glancing at the paper I would be very skeptical of someone who writes (14) just after (13). Did you double check the definition in the earlier references ?

Comment: not to mention that (16) also makes no sense

Comment: I doubted (14) was true, too. In Clark's paper[11], I couldn't found the word "Liouville number". I have read [10], which wrote the same definition as this paper. Why (16) makes no sense?

Comment: Did you mean that (17) is not true?

Comment: well I think he uses the wrong definition (14) then every number is Liouville and every sequence is Liouville. If he uses the right definition (13) then almost no number is Liouville, and no sequence is Liouville (because that would require that all the numbers are Liouville). Also I don't want to read any more of that paper now.

Comment: @mercio I see, thank you.